# Debug with release configuration of web.config

Tags: debugging, web-config, release

Is it possible to debug a web application in Visual Studio with the release configuration of web.config?

So we do a lot of transformation in the web.config file from development to release.
Is it possible to "run" the debug version but with the web.config file that would exist after the release transformation has been added?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the arrow next to Debug, you can access the configuration manager. There you can choose with what configuration you will debug.

Comment: So I tried that, both where i created a new configuration, and where I set the Debug version to use the release configuration, but none of them actually used the correct version of the config file.


Btw. if I use the "Publish Selection" and published to a folder, that folder has the correct web.config.

Comment: What if you create a new configuration, and copy from the release?